# How to convert binary python file to a readable format

Tags: python

I have a binary file that supposed to be a python function and I want to read it. right now when I open it and print the data thats what I get:

```
b'c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s3\x03\x00\x00d\x01\x00\x01\x03\x03\x03\t\x02\x02\t\x03\x03\x03\t\x02\x02\td\x02\x00d\x00\x00l\x00\x00}\x01\x00d\x02\x00d\x00\x00l\x01\x00}\x02\x00t\x02\x00\x83\x00\x00}\x03\x00d\x03\x00}\x00\x00t\x03\x00|\x03\x00\x83...'
```

Does someone knows how I can convert from this format to a readable data.

This is my python file that gave the output.

```
file = open('flag_function', 'rb')
data = file.read()
print(data)
# convert the data to a readable format
```

Comment: Is there some documentation that describes the format of the binary data?

Comment: You're dealing with Python bytecode. Printing it won't produce anything meaningful. What you need is a Python module to decompile python bytecode, such as `unpyc`.

Comment: now, I assumed that this is binary

Comment: it is python 2.7 file

Comment: @roee you aren't actually answering any of the questions. What do you mean by a "python 2.7 file" **exactly**? As someone already suggested, are these the bytecode cache files? i.e. `.pyc`? And what does it mean to say that the bianry is supposed to "be a python function"? You need to provide adequate details for people to actually help you here. Just saying you have a "binary file" essentially means "I have a file that is not a text file", so it pretty much tells us nothing useful except that it isn't text.

Comment: i got this file and I been told that this is a python 2.7 function. I need to convert it from what I'v got to a readable python code. I do'nt know what format the content is

Comment: That is not Python bytecode of any version.  I can't tell you what it is, but it's not Python code.

Comment: *then this is really a question for whoever gave you this file*. How are we supposed to know what data in an arbitrary format represents? Again, someone guessed it might just by a `.pyc` file, so you can try to decompile it using some third party library, e.g. https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/

Comment: @TimRoberts out of curiosity, what makes you say? the starting bytes?

Comment: Right.  I looked through my system to get good examples.  Python 2.7 pyc and pyo files start 0x03 0xf3 0x0d 0x0a.  Python 3.7 starts 0x42 0x0d 0x0d 0x0a.  None of them start with that many zeros.

Comment: i open the file in python using rb mode and print it

Comment: This file is a part of a ctf that I am trying to solve for the pas 3 days.

this is the link to the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/190Kt0sx6CRGpI_cUBgTEC98bGOG9EQAP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have been told that its a python 2.7 function that has been wrote on windows and nothing more

Comment: If you know the function name, you could import the file into Python and use `dis.dis()` to disassemble the byte codes. But turning it back into readable Python is harder. Why are you entering a CTF if you don't have the background information to solve it?